# Error codes on slack -- is this normal for an API?

Tags: api, rest, http, slack, http-status-codes

In Slack, it seems almost every response is a 200 OK, for example:

[image]

Is this common in APIs, or is this considered bad practice, or there's really no standard in the real world for how APIs return a good vs a bad response?

Comment: It is considered a bad practice, some 4xx would better fit.
You might contact slack support on the subject but keep in mind that http status codes are standards and might not be respected.

Even if you are able to drive on an opposite lane, it doesn't mean people will expect you to drive on this lane.
Returning a 2xx is totally fine, but it doesn't follow standards and everyone agrees (or should agree) to say it's shitty and should be a 4xx :)